# How to delete id from params after destroy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railscasts

I made sortable colums by RailsCast #228 Sortable Table Columns
Everything well work.
But when I add destroy record via ajax sort links doesn't work after delete

## application_helper.rb

```
#application_helper.rb
def sortable(column, title = nil)
 title ||= column.titleize
 css_class = (column == sort_column) ? "current #{sort_direction}" : nil
 direction = (column == sort_column && sort_direction == "asc") ? "desc" : "asc"
 link_to title,  params.merge(:sort => column, :direction => direction, page: nil),  {:class => css_class, remote: true }
 end
```

## contracts_controller.rb

```
#contracts_controller.rb
def destroy
 @contract.destroy
 if params[:limit]
  @contracts = Contract.includes(:department).order(sort_column + ' ' + sort_direction).page(params[:page]).per(params[:limit])
 else
  @contracts = Contract.includes(:department).order(sort_column + ' ' + sort_direction).page(params[:page])
 end
 respond_to do |format|
  format.html {}
  format.js {flash.now[:danger] = "Success delete"}
 end
end
```

## delete link

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', contract, remote: true, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } , class: 'btn btn-danger'%>
```

After destroy link to sort is `/contracts/1?direction=asc&sort=contractor`, but I need `/contracts?direction=asc&sort=contractor`

Comment: Try redirecting it to `index` after deletion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sortable` helper link might have to change like this,

```
link_to title,  your_index_path(params.merge(:sort => column, :direction => direction, page: nil)
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I use remote: true in link and format will be js

Comment: @AndreyDemidenko  you are right. answer is edited for ajax response

Comment: But then it will be no need remote: true.

Comment: It will solve problem. But when I need to use a sortable helper method for another model, I have to create a new method sortable.Is it good?

Comment: add extra parameter `path` in sortable method